# without Time Based Workflow

Tags: apex, trigger

i try to write a trigger for object. thats work  send email base of day like 3,5,7 days  for further user. have any idea how can we do this process . not allow the time base trigger using workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers only fire when an edit actually occurs on a record. There's no way to schedule/delay emails very nicely without the use of time-based workflow. That said, if you wanted to do so, you'd need a scheduled class and a batchable class, plus a custom field or a custom object to keep track of when the next notification should occur. You could use a trigger to fire the actual notifications, but only as part of a larger process.

```
public class NotificationTimerAndProcessor implements Database.Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            [SELECT Id FROM Object__c WHERE Notification_Date_1__c <= :Date.today()]);
        }
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Object__c[] records) {
        // Update records, send notifications here
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // No need to do anything, but this needs to be here
    }
}
```

At this point, you just need a trigger to set the date values, or an immediate workflow. You might also need some additional logic to keep that trigger from firing during your batch process so the notifications don't get repeated.

After all of this, I think you'll see that a simple time-based workflow would be far more efficient and less troublesome than trying to roll your own solution.